# How to make ASCII borders for cards in c++ and make 10 not to move them

Tags: c++, c

My question is: how to make ASCII borders for cards in my poker code? Everything works perfect until number 10 comes. All other cards "12345678910JQKA" contain 1 symbol but 10 contains 2 so it moves my ASCII borders.

Here is the code:

```
printf ("\n\nYour cards are:\n");
    printf ("   ___   ___   ___   ___   ___\n");
    printf ("  |%s  | |%s  | |%s  | |%s  | |%s  | \n", pack[0].value, pack[1].value, pack[2].value, pack[3].value, pack[4].value);
    printf ("  | %s | | %s | | %s | | %s | | %s | ", pack[0].suit, pack[1].suit, pack[2].suit, pack[3].suit, pack[4].suit );
    printf ("\n  |  %s| |  %s| |  %s| |  %s| |  %s| ", pack[0].value, pack[1].value, pack[2].value, pack[3].value, pack[4].value);
printf ("\n   ---   ---   ---   ---   --- ");
```

}

Ok found the answer.
It was %-2s for upper numbers so - made them still stay at the left and %2s for bottom numbers.

```
printf ("\n\nYour cards are:\n");
    printf ("   ___   ___   ___   ___   ___\n");
    printf ("  |%-2s | |%-2s | |%-2s | |%-2s | |%-2s | \n", pack[0].value, pack[1].value, pack[2].value, pack[3].value, pack[4].value);
    printf ("  | %s | | %s | | %s | | %s | | %s | ", pack[0].suit, pack[1].suit, pack[2].suit, pack[3].suit, pack[4].suit );
    printf ("\n  | %2s| | %2s| | %2s| | %2s| | %2s| ", pack[0].value, pack[1].value, pack[2].value, pack[3].value, pack[4].value);
printf ("\n   ---   ---   ---   ---   --- ");
```

Comment: I recommend investigating printf patterns further. For example, you can add a minimum width to a placeholder. `%2s` might do the trick (or `%2.2s` if you also want to set a maximum width).

Comment: Is it possible to add the width after the number since %2s makes a space before the number so it is not connected to the border anymore...and it should be. (%2s makes the number at the top in the middle and it should be at the top left corner)

Comment: This question has been crossposted to Code Review at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/49278/21609 where OP has already figured out a solution (using `%-2s` for left alignment).

Answer (score 0):

So make all your cards have 2 spaces for their symbols.

Comment: That's not exactly helpful - how?